# AEM SQL service

Tags: aem

Sorry if this has been answered before.  Long story short, I've been tasked to figure out a way to query content/pages to be able to display previews in a different page.  This isn't really a problem for me except I've never used AEM and the other devs here don't have web service experience.

From what I've seen is mentions of OSGi to creating a .NET service so I'm not exactly sure if what they're suggesting is overkill on what I'm trying to accomplish.  I was able to run the SQL query in CRXDE Lite (select * from nt:base where ....) and I can see the resource type values that I want to pull.  Is it possible to just create a JSP file with a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer, yes it's possible to query directly from a jsp, but it's a horrifically bad idea from a developer stance.

There are several ways of querying the repository, and it all depends on flavour and requirements. But it would be highly recommended to build a java service which abstracts the actual query implementation from your display logic (aka the JSP's). That way you can reuse your code in other places. If you are still bend on doing it directly in a JSP, you can use the QueryBuilder service directly to construct and execute queries rather than your own service. A basic example can be found on [adobe](https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/using/using-query-builder-api.html).

I query the repository in a number of ways, and they all depend on the context and complexity

- XPath (although deprecated - it still comes out on top as the fastest on a lot of queries and it won't disappear anytime soon I believe)
- [SQL or SQL2](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossdna/0.7/manuals/reference/html/jcr-query-and-search.html) (the link is for jboss docs, but the syntax is the same)
- [Predicates](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/dam/customizing_and_extendingcq5dam/query_builder.html)

The items above can be run in a number of ways, my personal flavour goes out the querybuilder api, or resourceResolver.findResources(String query,String language) depending on the context.

A helpful tool to test queries besides crx/de is /libs/cq/search/content/querydebug.html